# Navbar not being shown

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a python text editor and am adding an extra dropdown to the nav bar (called the menubar). However this does not display. It is done exactly the same format as the other sections. I am using the Tkinter tkFileDialog and tkMessageBox modules. This is the code that I have (just the tkinter):

```
root = Tk()
root.title("Text Editor")
root.minsize(width=400, height=400)
root.maxsize(width=400, height=400)

text = Text(root, width=400, height=400)
text.pack()

#File Menu

menubar = Menu(root)

filemenu = Menu(menubar)
filemenu.add_command(label="New", command=newFile)
filemenu.add_command(label="Open", command=openFile)
filemenu.add_command(label="Save", command=saveFile)
filemenu.add_command(label="Save As", command=saveAs)
filemenu.add_separator()
filemenu.add_command(label="Quit", command=root.quit)
menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)

#Edit menu

editmenu = Menu(menubar)
editmenu.add_command(label="Copy", command=copy)
editmenu.add_command(label="Cut", command=cut)
editmenu.add_command(label="Paste", command=paste)
menubar.add_cascade(label="Edit", menu=editmenu)
#Edit commands
rightClick = Menu(root, tearoff=0)
rightClick.add_command(label="Copy", command=copy)
rightClick.add_command(label="Cut", command=cut)
rightClick.add_command(label="Paste", command=paste)

text.bind("<Button-3>", popup)

#format does nothing yet
formatmenu = Menu(menubar)
formatmenu.add_command(label="Bold", command=doNothing)
formatmenu.add_command(label="Italic", command=doNothing)
formatmenu.add_command(label="Underline", command=doNothing)
formatmenu.add_cascade(label="Format", menu=formatmenu)

root.config(menu=menubar)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo(ish).

```
formatmenu.add_cascade(label="Format", menu=formatmenu)
```

should be:

```
menubar.add_cascade(label="Format", menu=formatmenu)
```